# unity 3d android studio

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm making an Augmented Reality Treasure Hunt Game based within my university campus, and struggling with integrating unity with Android Studio. 
I'm have created the GUI (Splash screen, Main Menu, Options Screen etc.) on Android Studio and need to create another Activity which allows the user to open up the Camera to locate virtual objects (which I have created in Unity 3d already).

The problem here is: 
how to integrate my Unity Project scene into the app I have created in Android studio, which only opens when the user presses a button on the game screen (to open up the camera and identify the unity objects)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can get the information you're looking for [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25629827/integrating-unity3d-game-into-android-ios-activity), [there](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/using-unity-android-in-a-sub-view.98315/) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24564470/unity3d-and-android-studio-integration).